# Control what I see in my app feed

Tags: feature-request, android-app, android-app-feed

Maybe this is in the app but I can't seem to find it.

I'd like to be able to control what's in the SE app's feed. Right now it seems to be a random collection of hot questions from the entire network; stuff I have no interest in. Is there a way to specify that I only want it to show items from certain sites on the network? Or a way to configure what type of items show up in there, reputation changes etc...

Comment: I searched (in the app) and the duplicate didn't show up. My bad.